# Best way to set up Google Analytics for domain, subdomain and subdirectories

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, tracking, universal-analytics

I have a website with following domain and folder structure:

- Main Website: www.ry.com
- Subdomain1:   mobile.ry.com
- Subdomain2:   speed.ry.com
- Directory1:   www.ry.com/mobile
- Directory2:   www.ry.com/blog

I have just started setting up Google Analytics for this and I am totally confused as to what are the best practices that should be followed? Should I consider them as individual properties or just 1 property. Should I be setting up a different GA code for each one of these?

Ideally, I would like to track all of it at one place but at the same time, using some filters be able to see the traffic on any one of the subdomains/subdirectories.

I started reading up about  Universal Analytics but got totally confused and some of the posts were outdated as GA and UA seems to have changed significantly in the recent  times.

Please advise me about how to set this up or point me to any good blogs or urls that are a rich resource.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most complete answers I've found for this question.
http://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-subdomain-tracking-in-google-analytics